# how to check if a text is highlighted on the page using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

M facing problem in validating whether text "Save permissions" is highlighted or not.

```html
<div class="o-grid">
<div class="o-grid__col o-grid__col--1-of-1">
<div class="c-page-actions">
<div class="c-page-actions__primary">
<button id="btnSavePermission" class="c-button c-button--big-text c-button--icon-right c-button--hug-right" data-button-enabled-when-form-edited="" disabled="">
<div class="c-button__inner-wrapper">
                            Save permissions                             
<svg class="c-icon c-icon--color-yellow" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: You can check the back ground color of the text to verify highlighted or not. Most of the time it is in blue color if it is in blue color, it is highlighted. check the background color for your application when it is highlighted.

Comment: I tried but m not getting the correct output. I there any simpler way to validate.

Comment: is it a label on the button? if yes, how will it gets highlighted?

Comment: Yes, it's a label on button. Actually on checking a check box on the similar page, 'Save permissions' label get's highlighted and button get's activated.

Comment: instead of checking for highlighted , you can check for enabled or not?

Comment: @B123 Update the question with the relevant HTML of both the conditions, element being highlighted and element not being highlighted

Comment: @B123 please check my answer it may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement btnSavePerm = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSavePermission"));
if( btnSavePerm != null && btnSavePerm.isDisplayed() ){
     if(!btnSavePerm.getAttribute("disabled").equals(""))
     {
      System.out.println("button is highlighted or enabled");
     }
     else{
       System.out.println("button is not highlighted or enabled");
     }
}
```